# Issue with Object returned when using Linq Where clause

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have the following code:

```
IList<CmsUserPermissionGroup> matchingRoles = PermissionGroups.Where(r => r.JournalCode.ToLower() == journalCode.ToLower())
                                                              .Where(r => r.CmsRole.ToLower() == role.ToLower())
                                                              .Where(r => r.AccessLevel > 0)
```

that I assumed would return an empty List if no results are returned. What is actually returned is the following error:

> ***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Am I misunderstanding something? What other alternative is there?

Comment: Are you certain that the NullReferenceException is not being generated because you are calling ToLower() on some property of an instance that is null?

Comment: It seems that is the case, as has been highlighted in the answers below - thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there was no problem with the query, an empty enumeration would be returned.

The problem here is inside your `Where()` statements. Either `JournalCode` or `CmsRole` are null (assuming you already checked `journalCode` and `role` for null values somewhere else) on one of the objects in `PermissionGroups`. When you call `ToLower()` on that value, it throws the above Exception.

You could protect yourself a little better with the following:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(journalCode) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(role))
{
    Roles =
        PermissionGroups
            .Where(r => r.JournalCode != null
                        && r.JournalCode.Equals(journalCode,
                            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            .Where(r => r.CmsRole != null
                        && r.CmsRole.Equals(role,
                            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            .Where(r => r.AccessLevel > 0);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you could just use *String.Equals ( journalCode, r.JournalCode, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase );* This will automatically guard against both strings being null - and will return true if both are null (useful if that is what you want to happen!)

Answer (score 2):

It *will* return an empty sequence if no results are returned *and the predicates succeeded*.

As it happens, it looks like either `r` was null for some element, or `r.JournalCode` was null for some element, or `journalCode` was null, or `r.CmsRole` was null for some element, or `role` was null. LINQ doesn't prevent these exceptions from bubbling up.

Comment: So, how do we prevent these exceptions from bubbling up? I've similar case posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39382660/1232087) where `t.price` is throwing this exception when t.price is null in the LEFT OUTER join (that happens when join condition is not met)

Comment: @nam: Detect and handle it - don't dereference `t` if it might be null...