# LINQ equivalent of SQL IsNull(..,..) in the Where Clause

Tags: c#, linq

In the following OUTER JOIN LINQ query I'm getting the null exception in the `Where` clause if a right side row is null (in case c.CustomerID does not match ord.CustomerID in the Outer Join). **Question**: How can I handle the case if ord.price is null in the below `Where clause` **Note**: price is nullable columns of type `int?`.

```
Query1 = from c in Customers
             join ord in Orders on c.CustomerId equals ord.CustomerId into cord
               from t in cord.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where t.price = null || t.price > 100
             select new {CustName = c.Name, OrderID = (t == null ? 0 : t.OrderId)};
```

**UPDATE**:

I'm sorry, there was a typo in the where clause.

1. As @ JeffMercado pointed out, it should be `t.price` and **not** `ord.price`
2. There was a clause missing in the `Where` clause. I've corrected it to: `where t.price = null || t.price > 100`. But now I'm getting the error: `operator || cannot be applied to operands of type '<null>' and 'int'`

Comment: If price is nullable, then you can add a condition in where clause i.e. where ord.price > 100 && ord.price != null

Comment: @RohitGarg  Sorry, there was a typo in the post. I've added an **Update** section to the post.

Comment: @RohitGarg  he has to put ord.price != null before the short circuit "AND" like this " ord.price != null  && ord.price > 100" if got null then the second condition will not be checked. :)

Comment: The variable `ord` is not accessible in that context... You should be getting a syntax error long before you even gotten to the NRE.

Comment: Note: price is nullable columns of type int? is it nullable integer "int?" or only int and a question mark for question mark like  "int   ?"

Comment: @JeffMercado You are correct. I've made the correction and noted it in the UPDATE section of my post. But the real error is still there.

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman It's a nullable integer as `int?`

Comment: Did you tried my first comment? Put the  null coalescing operator before another condition in each answer

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman I've `Where t.price = null || t.price > 100` but getting the error `operator || cannot be applied to operands of type '<null>' and 'int'`

Comment: Then do like this  -  "Where t.price ?? 0 = 0 || t.price > 100"

Comment: `null` check should be similar to `select`: `where t == null || t.price > 100`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
Query1 = from c in Customers
             join ord in Orders on c.CustomerId equals ord.CustomerId into cord
               from t in cord.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where (ord.price ?? 0) > 100
             select new {CustName = c.Name, OrderID = (t == null ? 0 : t.OrderId)};
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Using your suggestion, I'm getting the error `operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'`. I'm not sure but it may have something to do with a **Note** in my post.

Comment: Then price is not nullable, it must be of type int?.

Comment: Yes it is as I noted in my **Note** in the post.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the post. I've added an **Update** section to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax problem there:

```
where t.price = null || t.price > 100
```

Should be:

```
where t.price == null || t.price > 100
```

*note the: **==***

What is happening is you're assigning `t.price = null` the result of that is `null`.
So effectively it resolves too `null ||  t.price > 100` which is why the compiler is giving you:

> operator || cannot be applied to operands of type '<null>' and 'int'